# No module named 'analog_swig'

Tags: software-defined-radio, rtl-sdr, gnuradio, usrp

I know guys you gonna tell me tat there is something wrong about GnuRadio or Pybombs installation. Well, this is my third time during the past 48 hours I reformat the OS of my mini pc fitlet2 mint linux and reinstall the the OS which is mint 19.1 cinamon and reinstall gnuradio using apt-get or even using Pybombs and get this problem when I try Python3 to run my .py file. Please, I am in real need for your help, again, I am a real beginner and try to learn.
Here is how I installed Pybombs:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo pip3 install wheel
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo pip3 install pybombs
pybombs auto-config
pybombs recipes add-defaults
pybombs prefix init ~/gnuradio -R gnuradio-default
pybombs install gr-osmosdr
pip install analog
sudo uhd_images_downloader
. ~/gnuradio/setup_env.sh
gnuradio companion
```

Later, I learned Kevin here on this community how to generate a python code from Gnuradion to run it through a python web server that I built based on simple script that I've found online. When I run it using python3 I get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gnuradio'" error.

[image]

[image]

I know you may say something again about editing the PYTHONPATH file, and that is the other problem to be honest. I mean I am not sure what I am suppose to change aboutthe steup_env.sh file? Shouldn't be set and ready to go! If not, then please, guide me on how to do it.

This is my setup_env.sh file:

[image]

Update:

I just noticed that when I run 'Pybombs run gnuradio companion' the interface itself, it generated this error:

```
<<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.7.13.5 >>>

Block paths:
    /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
    /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks

Loading: "/media/fit-pc/DA54CCFE54CCDDFF/Mint Linux stuff/mint backup/My-Projects/FM-Radio-Receiver/FM-Radio-Receiver.grc"
>>> Done

Generating: '/media/fit-pc/DA54CCFE54CCDDFF/Mint Linux stuff/mint backup/My-Projects/FM-Radio-Receiver/top_block.py'

Executing: /usr/bin/python2 -u /media/fit-pc/DA54CCFE54CCDDFF/Mint Linux stuff/mint backup/My-Projects/FM-Radio-Receiver/top_block.py

gr-osmosdr v0.1.4-127-g4d83c606 (0.1.5git) gnuradio 3.7.13.5
built-in source types: file osmosdr fcd rtl rtl_tcp uhd hackrf bladerf rfspace airspy soapy redpitaya 
[0;32m[INFO] [UHD] [0;39mlinux; GNU C++ version 7.4.0; Boost_106501; UHD_3.15.0.git-16-gcad30dfe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/fit-pc/DA54CCFE54CCDDFF/Mint Linux stuff/mint backup/My-Projects/FM-Radio-Receiver/top_block.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
  File "/media/fit-pc/DA54CCFE54CCDDFF/Mint Linux stuff/mint backup/My-Projects/FM-Radio-Receiver/top_block.py", line 183, in main
    tb = top_block_cls()
  File "/media/fit-pc/DA54CCFE54CCDDFF/Mint Linux stuff/mint backup/My-Projects/FM-Radio-Receiver/top_block.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.osmosdr_source_0 = osmosdr.source( args="numchan=" + str(1) + " " + '' )
  File "/home/fit-pc/gnuradio/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/osmosdr_swig.py", line 1170, in make
    return _osmosdr_swig.source_make(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: No supported devices found (check the connection and/or udev rules).
```

The other thing that I just noticed is when I run the Pybombs GR in the terminal it shows warnings "blocks already exist", but then the programs starts normally:

```
fit-pc@fitpc-fitlet2:~$ pybombs run gnuradio-companion
PyBOMBS.ConfigManager - INFO - Prefix Python version is: 3.6.8
PyBOMBS - INFO - PyBOMBS Version 2.3.3
Warning: Block with key "analog_agc2_xx" already exists.
    Ignoring: /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_agc2_xx.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_agc3_xx" already exists.
    Ignoring: /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_agc3_xx.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_agc_xx" already exists.
    Ignoring: /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_agc_xx.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_am_demod_cf" already exists.
    Ignoring: /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_am_demod_cf.xml
Warning: Block with key "analog_const_source_x" already exists.
    Ignoring: /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/analog_const_source_x.xml
..

..

..

..
Warning: Block with key "zeromq_sub_msg_source" already exists.
    Ignoring: /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/zeromq_sub_msg_source.xml
Warning: Block with key "zeromq_sub_source" already exists.
    Ignoring: /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks/zeromq_sub_source.xml
<<< Welcome to GNU Radio Companion 3.7.13.5 >>>

Block paths:
    /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks
    /home/fit-pc/gnuradio/share/gnuradio/grc/blocks

Loading: "/media/fit-pc/DA54CCFE54CCDDFF/Mint Linux stuff/mint backup/My-Projects/FM-Radio-Receiver/FM-Radio-Receiver.grc"
>>> Done
```

Update:

The "NO supported devices ..." error is fixed now after I run "/home/fit-pc/gnuradio/lib/uhd/utils/uhd_images_downloader.py", so the gnuradio gui/interface works and generates output normally with the usrp. But

But I still have the original error there which is "No module named 'analog_swig'" whenever I run python3 /home/fit-pc/Desktop/python-web-server/serv.py  in the terminal.

Here i my original .grc file (the ID here is top_block and not Exercise_1 for demonstration purposes):

[image]

And to generate my python code to run it through the web server I had to remove the FFT sink, Multiply Const, and the Slider and run it as "No Gui" as I was instructed before:

[image]

My last Update:

If I run it using python2.7 in the Terminal I get this and nothing happens:

[image]

Comment: GNU Radio 3.7 is not python3 compatible. As you can in fact easily see from your module paths, which contain `python2.7`.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is a little disappointing - are you aware if Python 3 migration is a work in progress?

Comment: more than aware. As soon as I release GNU Radio 3.8, Python3 will be the preferred Python version, and with 3.9, we'll drop Python2 support, @flow2k.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Actually, to me, this is a real good news! At least I know that whatever I did was not wrong. Beside, I learned some good stuff while digging around this issue during the past a few days. Most important, I can move to my next phase in my GnuRadio training. I will take this as an answer to my posting. Thanks Marcus.

Comment: You should really not be using pybombs at this point; mint should ship `gnuradio` and `gnuradio-dev`, and that's all you'd need for working GNU Radio.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, would you please elaborate more on that. I really appreciate your knowledge and patience.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Should I remove pybombs? Is it going to cause me any issues in the future?

Comment: yes, try to work without pybombs for now. Pybombs is extremely mighty if you want to develop for multiple target platforms with competing versions of GNU Radio... You don't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I just did. Thanks again Marcus.

Comment: Hadad, when trying to troubleshoot a problem, please don't post the next set of symptoms as a new similar question. @MarcusMüller  Could you post an answer to https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/14892/no-module-named-gnuradio since running Python 3 is at the root of the situation?

Comment: @Kevin, You mean post the solution as another update or just a comment?

Comment: @Hadad Neither — If you have a solution to the problem then you should post it as an **answer**. The goal of Stack Exchange is to have **answered questions**, so it's good to answer your own questions if you can. It's best if, once you know what the problem is, you can also simplify the question down to describing the relevant parts rather than a lengthy troubleshooting process. If you make sure your questions get *answered, usefully,* and that the question clearly explains what situation the answer applies to, then it's much more OK to post more separate questions.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Great to hear about the support for Python 3!